# Pyspark convert decimal to date

Tags: pyspark

I see there are methods to convert string to date, but I don't see any way we can convert decimal to string. In one of the tables I am working on, date is in format `20170924.00000`. Is it possible to convert this into a valid date format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to int, then cast to string, then specify input format to to_date function to get your output.

(**welcome to SO)**

```
df.show()

+-----------+
|date       |
+-----------+
| 20170924.0|
+-----------+ 



from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.col("date").cast("int").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd")).show()

+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2017-09-24|
+----------+
```

Comment: The format shows "yyyymmdd", but result shows 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Maybe a typo